adding quotes to set of comma separated IP addresses in notepad++
Please, I have a set of comma separated IP addresses and I want to add quotes to each IP addresses to that I can assign the set a powershell variable and parse each IP address strings in the variable using "foreach" to do some remote access commands.
the IP Addresses range from  10.196.20.100 to last 10.190.20.254 are below:
10.196.20.100,10.196.20.101,10.196.20.102,10.196.20.103,.........,10.196.20.254

The problem is that I dont want to manually add to quotes to each IP addresses before I can use them as strings in powershell.
So I tried to use the "replace" search in notepad++ with regex to find each IP addresses as part of the search string using the pattern below
Find what: .{2}\..{3}\..{2}\..{3}
Replace with: "\1"
Result, each IP address including the comma is replace " "  as below:
" ", " "," "," ",.........," "

instead of
"10.196.20.100","10.196.20.101","10.196.20.102","10.196.20.103",.........,"10.196.20.254"


You don't have capture group in your regex so you can't use it in the replacement part.
Two solutions:

Use "$0" in Replace with.
Use (.{2}\..{3}\..{2}\..{3}) in the Find what part. Note the parenthesis.
2.1. and "$1" in Replace with part.


Your search string is not specific enough. It will also find
the string ,.........,10 from your example.
You should use the following:
Find what : \d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d{3}
Replace by : "$0"
Where \d stands for a digit.
Another option is :
Find what : (\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})
Replace by : "$1"
